# automatically change value on the table mysql

Tags: mysql, automation

i have table invoice in my database that contain atributes 'due date', 'date' and 'status'. What i want is data on 'status' change automatically. Example, status (unpaid change to expired) when date past the due date. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Which is your version of MySQL?

Comment: latest version i think

Comment: Which is your OS?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this. The more traditional way is with a cron job on the server:

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5

Another way is to do it with MySQL events:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html

I personally prefer to keep this kind of logic in the app via a cron job and keep mysql events dedicated to db maintenance related items (partition maintenance for instance).